# how to convert multi array to json multi array

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

i have foreach loop that returns multi-array from the database
 and i want to convert this array to multi array in  json ,

how to do this ?

php array example

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [it_code] => 2894
            [it_quantity] => 300
            [it_price] => 0
            [it_notes] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [it_code] => 2894
            [it_quantity] => 284
            [it_price] => 0
            [it_notes] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [it_code] => 2894
            [it_quantity] => 4
            [it_price] => 0
            [it_notes] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [it_code] => 2894
            [it_quantity] => 3
            [it_price] => 0
            [it_notes] => 
        )

)
```

i want returned json to be like this format

```
 [
            ['2894', 300, 0,''],
            ['2894', 284, 0,''],
            ['2894', 4, 0,''],
            ['2894', 3, 0,''],
            ['2894', 10, 0, '']
        ]
```

my code like this

```
$this->db->where("it_parent_item", $parent_id);
$this->db->select("d_items.it_code,d_items_type.it_ty_ar_desc,d_items.it_quantity,d_items.it_price,it_notes");
$this->db->join('d_items_type','d_items_type.it_ty_id=d_items.it_type','left');
$this->db->from("d_items");
$result = $this->db->get()->result_array();


echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: is [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Henders, that won't remove the `keys` (if that's what the op is looking for), but it's worth a shot. So, do you have to remove the keys (`it_..`)?

Comment: Good point, didn't think about reformatting...

Comment: as you said i want to remove the keys before convert it to json

Comment: i want only the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to convert integer to string

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($sourceArray as $element) {
    $newArray[] = array_values($element);
}

array_walk_recursive($newArray, 
function(&$value, $key){
    $value = (string)$value;
});

print_r (json_encode($newArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that other answers will give `null` instead of `''`.

So, without using `array_values`, this code returns all values, but in case there is any null, it returns `''` instead (as expected in the question):

```
$arr = array();
foreach($foo as $value){
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($value as $v){
        $tmp[] = $v===null ? '' : $v;
    }
    $arr[] = $tmp;
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Output:

> [[2894,300,0,""],[2894,284,0,""],[2894,4,0,""],[2894,3,0,""]]

```
[
    [2894,300,0,""],
    [2894,284,0,""],
    [2894,4,0,""],
    [2894,3,0,""]
]
```

This a copyable array:

```
$foo = array
(
    0 => array
        (
            'it_code' => 2894,
            'it_quantity' => 300,
            'it_price' => 0,
            'it_notes' => null
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'it_code' => 2894,
            'it_quantity' => 284,
            'it_price' => 0,
            'it_notes' => null
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'it_code' => 2894,
            'it_quantity' => 4,
            'it_price' => 0,
            'it_notes' => null
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'it_code' => 2894,
            'it_quantity' => 3,
            'it_price' => 0,
            'it_notes' => null
        ),

);
```

Comment: Nice solution! Is this going to be more intensive than using `array_values()`?

Comment: TBH, I don't know if it will be more intensive, but in that case, `array_values` doesn't return `''` when the value is `null`... @Henders

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you want to loop through your array so it's formatted how you want in PHP and then convert that PHP array into JSON:

```
$dataArray = array(); //The array containing your values
$jsonArray = array(); //The array which will be formatted for json

foreach($dataArray as $value){
    $keylessValues = array_values($value);
    $jsonArray[] = $keylessValues;
}

$jsonArray = json_encode($jsonArray); //This is now a JSON array storing your values
```

What we do here is move through the array and then take only the values with [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) and put them into a new index in our `$jsonArray`.

Once we have moved through the entire array we can convert our newly formatted and populated array into JSON with [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

It's worth noting that your values that are set as `''` will come through as `null`. If you need those values as `''` instead of `null` have a look at the answer @FirstOne gave.

Comment: Just note that instead of `''`, this returns `null`.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that in my test but forgot to put it in!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the initial array (shown like a PHP array, but the same as your post):

```
$initialArray = array(
    array(
        "it_code"     => 2894,
        "it_quantity" => 300,
        "it_price"    => 0,
        "it_notes"    => '',
    ),
    array(
        "it_code"     => 2894,
        "it_quantity" => 284,
        "it_price"    => 0,
        "it_notes"    => '',
    ),
    array(
        "it_code"     => 2894,
        "it_quantity" => 4,
        "it_price"    => 0,
        "it_notes"    => '',
    ),
    array(
        "it_code"     => 2894,
        "it_quantity" => 3,
        "it_price"    => 0,
        "it_notes"    => '',
    ),
);
```

You can loop over each element, assigning just the values to a new set of arrays, like this:

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($initialArray as $subArray)
{
    $newArray[] = array_values($subArray);
}
```

The resulting array will look like this:

```
[[2894,300,0,""],[2894,284,0,""],[2894,4,0,""],[2894,3,0,""]]
```

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ','`on: `it_notes    => ,`

Comment: Fixed, those pesky null values for `it_notes`.

Comment: Sure, depends what the user wants. But hopefully these will get him started on reformatting the array, and maybe the SQL query can return more useful values instead of null.